# How to retrieve Firebase key using Angular resource and firebase-admin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I built a RESTful application running node on server side, like express and firebase-admin. I made some API endpoints linked with my Firebase project database.

On client side I am using Angular resource to consume the API. Below is a part of my routes file, where resolves a resource service named 'BeerService':

```
.state('beers', {
                    url: '/beers',
                    templateUrl: 'app/beer/beer.html',
                    controller: 'BeerCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    resolve: {
                        beers: function(BeerService) {
                            return BeerService.query(function(data) {
                                console.info(data);
                                return data;
                            }, function(error) {
                                console.error(error);
                                return error;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
```

It returns `data` and save it to `beers`. Then it was injected on my controller and saved in a global variable named `vm.beers`. On the html there is a ng-repeat (beer in vm.beers) and {{beer}}.

The problem: beer only shows the values from object. How can I get the keys of these nodes?

This is the output of `console.info(data)` from file above (There is just one record in db with key -KXHTyo8AWFehyJ2iIY_):

[image: console output]

This is the html:

```
<h5>GET /api/beers</h5>
<button ng-click="vm.queryBeers()" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
    Refresh
</button>
<ul class="demo-list-item mdl-list">
    <li class="mdl-list__item" ng-repeat="beer in vm.beers">
        <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
            {{beer}}
        </span>
    </li>
    {{vm.beers}}
</ul>
```

And this is shown:

[image: screen]

Could you help me to know how I can get the key from the data (-KXHTyo8AWFehyJ2iIY_)?

Comment: well, nobody answer how to get the node key using firebase methods..so here is an alternative, set a child with key created using push method like below:

`saveBeer: function(req, res, next) {
        var ref = beersRef.push();
        var key = ref.key;
        ref.set({
            key: key,
            msg: 'Drink me!',
            level: 9000
        }, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                res.sendStatus(400);
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(200);
            }
        });
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on documentation. Here is:

```
// Assume we have the following data in our database:
{
  "users": {
    "ada": {
      "first": "Ada",
      "last": "Lovelace"
    },
    "alan": {
      "first": "Alan",
      "last": "Turing"
    }
  }
}

// Loop through users in order with the forEach() method. The callback provided
// to will be called synchronously with a DataSnapshot for each child:
var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
query.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      // childData will be the actual contents of the child
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  });
});
```